# filemanager plugin - TinyMCE - the server response wasn't JSON format

Tags: javascript, php, json, tinymce

recently we updated a server from php 5.3 to php 7, actually I don't know if the update causes this issue, but when I go to insert a file on TinyMCE javascirpt I receive this error message:

> The server response wasn't JSON format

I haven't found anything on internet about it.

here is Json_data:

```
{"method":"fm.insertFiles","params":[{"path0":"{0}/Sage.JPG"}],"id":"c0"}
```

here is TinyMCE configuration:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
        mode : "exact",
        elements : "msg_body",
    theme : "advanced",
    theme_advanced_resizing_max_width : 530,
    plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave,spellchecker,filemanager",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,|,styleselect,formatselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,<?if ($staff[perm][msg_replies]==1) {?>|,insertfile,link,<?}?>|,spellchecker",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    //External
    extended_valid_elements : "iframe[src|width|height|name|align]",

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "../style-bijou.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "cms-image_list.php",
    media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

    // Style formats
    style_formats : [
        {title : 'Bijou Weddings styles'},
        {title : 'Bijou copy', block : 'p', classes : 'copy'},
        {title : 'Bijou copy bold', inline : 'span', classes : 'title'},
        {title : 'Corporate Event styles'},
        {title : 'Event bullets small', block : 'p', classes : 'corpbodybull'},
        {title : 'Event bullets big', block : 'p', classes : 'corpbull'},
        {title : 'Table styles'},
        {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
    ],

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }

});
```

Do you have any idea please?
thanks

Comment: Really? You haven't found anything? May you share the JSON?

Comment: that message error is generate by plugin "filemanager", I haven't found anything regarding that message error related to that plugin "filemanager" for TinyMCE

Comment: there is no json_data: that code is generate by TinyMCE plugin, sorry I couldn't make myself clear

Comment: The filemanager plugin is not something that TinyMCE provides - its a 3rd party plugin. If that is causing the error you should contact the people who wrote that plugin.  I would also change the title of your post to more correctly reference the issue is with the filemanager plugin and not TinyMCE itself - the current title is misleading.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found what caused the problem,

The plugin "filemanager" generate a php error, the file `History.php` located in folder `/plugins/filemanager/plugins/History` is using a php function called `split` which is obsoleted for php7.

So I swap the function `split` with function `explode`. Now the file inserting is working properly.

Hope this will be useful.

here is the explanation in php.net:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php
and 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I had exactly the same problem and your solution potentially saved me hours of troubleshooting.

Comment: You are welcome, that's the idea of having a share place to help each others. I couldn't fix it if I didn't have access to the php error logs by the way

Answer (score 1):

Try to send the response with 
`$data = {"method":"fm.insertFiles","params":[{"path0":"{0}/Sage.JPG"}],"id":"c0"};
json_encode($data);`
 
intead of `json_data`

Comment: Hi Marco, 

The json data is generate by the plugin, so it's a error of the TinyMCE javascript plugin, I manage the TinyMCE through javascipt, I don't send the json call directly.

Sorry if I couldn't make myself clear

Comment: are you using a selector as a container to have a response? and what is `elements : "msg_body",`?

Comment: The "msg_body" is a CSS class, the "mgs_body" class is assigned to a HTML textarea, the javascript loads the TinyMCE plugin against the textarea, this is the way TinyMCE works

Comment: Try tu use selector instead of elements, https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/

Comment: Thanks Marco, I fixed it, have a look at the answer below, the problem was on a plugin, it used obsoleted functions no supported by php7 anymore.